# Automatic loading of other queries with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I would like to load a page of a site, but this one called different queries. I used [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tamper-data/), the page is called 4 requests before charging.
When I load the page with `HttpWebRequest`, the page loads without considering the 4 queries.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
static public void loadPage(CookieContainer cookieJar)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://page");
        request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 10;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        string html = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
        {
            html = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }
        response.Close();

        File.WriteAllText("index.html", html);
    }
```

Here is the result queries loaded when I call `https://page` :

```
# https://page/?getFiles=....
# https://page/?getFolders=...
# https://page/?groups=...
# https://page/?upload=...
```

*How can I automatically load queries at the same time as the page?*

Comment: Is it a page you have control over? Because if Tamper Data wants to load 4 other requests, it's because there's content on the page triggering those 4 request.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen : I think that it's requests AJAX. The question is this one: I have to load these 4 pages with HttpWebRequest or there is a way to load  automatically when I load https://page?

Comment: If you need to find it dynamically, I would think you'll need to parse the response for the additional requests and then launch those in new webrequests yourself, possible hook into browser functionality yourself for some screen scraping. Depends a lot on what you're actually trying to achieve/what the goal is.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen : Thus I'm obliged to load four requests with HttpWebRequest? It is an on-line storage site, the page is [link](https:// www.firedrive.com/myfiles) and the requests load files and directories.